# Using a separate Controller for Interception

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have created a `Controller` named `InterceptionLogger.java` which will contain only the `Interception` methods. The other `Controller` namely `Application` will contain all the `action` methods and use the `Interception` using the `@With` annotation.

This is the `Application.java` Controller:

```
@With(InterceptionLogger.class)
public class Application extends Controller {

public static void index() {
    System.out.println("Inside index!!!");
    render();
}

public static void welcome(String txtName){     
    render(txtName);
}
```

If the `InterceptionLogger.java` Controller is this:

```
public class InterceptionLogger extends Controller {   

@Before
static void logBefore(){
    System.out.println("Inside \"logBefore\" method of App Controller");
}

@After
static void logAfter(){
    System.out.println("Inside \"logAfter\" method of App Controller");
}

}
```

When I run the Application, the **Output is:**

```
Inside "logBefore" method of App Controller
Inside index!!!
Inside "logAfter" method of App Controller
```

Fine, as expected.

But If I change the `InterceptionLogger.java` to this:

```
public class InterceptionLogger extends Controller {   

@Before(only="welcome")
static void logBefore(){
    System.out.println("Inside \"logBefore\" method of App Controller");
}

@After(only="index")
static void logAfter(){
    System.out.println("Inside \"logAfter\" method of App Controller");
}

}
```

Then I am getting this **output** for `index` :

```
Inside index!!!
```

In this case, why is the statement `Inside "logAfter" method of App Controller` not getting printed in the console?

How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play! is looking for the intercepted methods in the current controller.  You need to supply the full path, if the method is in another controller:

```
@Before(only="Application.welcome")
static void logBefore(){
    System.out.println("Inside \"logBefore\" method of App Controller");
}

@After(only="Application.index")
static void logAfter(){
    System.out.println("Inside \"logAfter\" method of App Controller");
}
```